# MySQL 5.7.37 is consuming CPU and High memory ( 90-95% )

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, linux, cpu

I have a problem with my MySQL database.
RAM usage is too high, CPU too.

Does it come from my configuration ?

Here's my configuration :

```
auto_generate_certs ON
auto_increment_increment    1
auto_increment_offset   1
autocommit  ON
automatic_sp_privileges ON
avoid_temporal_upgrade  OFF
back_log    80
basedir /usr/
big_tables  OFF
bind_address    *
binlog_cache_size   32768
binlog_checksum CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
binlog_error_action ABORT_SERVER
binlog_format   ROW
binlog_group_commit_sync_delay  0
binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count 0
binlog_gtid_simple_recovery ON
binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
binlog_order_commits    ON
binlog_row_image    FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events    OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768
binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size  25000
binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking  COMMIT_ORDER
block_encryption_mode   aes-128-ecb
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
character_set_client    latin1
character_set_connection    latin1
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   latin1
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
check_proxy_users   OFF
collation_connection    latin1_swedish_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
completion_type NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert   AUTO
connect_timeout 10
core_file   OFF
datadir /var/lib/mysql/
date_format %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_authentication_plugin   mysql_native_password
default_password_lifetime   0
default_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_week_format 0
delay_key_write ON
delayed_insert_limit    100
delayed_insert_timeout  300
delayed_queue_size  1000
disabled_storage_engines    
disconnect_on_expired_password  ON
div_precision_increment 4
end_markers_in_json OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency    OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit   200
event_scheduler OFF
expire_logs_days    5
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp ON
flush   OFF
flush_time  0
foreign_key_checks  ON
ft_boolean_syntax   + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len 84
ft_min_word_len 4
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
ft_stopword_file    (built-in)
general_log OFF
general_log_file    /var/lib/mysql/41838e92fa49.log
group_concat_max_len    1024
gtid_executed   
gtid_executed_compression_period    1000
gtid_mode   OFF
gtid_owned  
gtid_purged 
have_compress   YES
have_crypt  YES
have_dynamic_loading    YES
have_geometry   YES
have_openssl    YES
have_profiling  YES
have_query_cache    YES
have_rtree_keys YES
have_ssl    YES
have_statement_timeout  YES
have_symlink    DISABLED
host_cache_size 279
hostname    41838e92fa49
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF
ignore_db_dirs  
init_connect    
init_file   
init_slave  
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts    8
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF
innodb_api_trx_level    0
innodb_autoextend_increment 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size   134217728
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown ON
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct 25
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 4294967296
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering all
innodb_checksum_algorithm   crc32
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5
innodb_compression_level    6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    
innodb_deadlock_detect  ON
innodb_default_row_format   dynamic
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF
innodb_doublewrite  ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_format  Barracuda
innodb_file_format_check    ON
innodb_file_format_max  Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table   ON
innodb_fill_factor  100
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1
innodb_flush_method 
innodb_flush_neighbors  1
innodb_flush_sync   ON
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_ft_aux_table 
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table 
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_large_prefix ON
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  16777216
innodb_log_checksums    ON
innodb_log_compressed_pages ON
innodb_log_file_size    3221225472
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   ./
innodb_log_write_ahead_size 8192
innodb_lru_scan_depth   100
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75.000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0.000000
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0
innodb_max_undo_log_size    1073741824
innodb_monitor_disable  
innodb_monitor_enable   
innodb_monitor_reset    
innodb_monitor_reset_all    
innodb_numa_interleave  OFF
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728
innodb_open_files   2000
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF
innodb_page_cleaners    4
innodb_page_size    16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 300
innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency    128
innodb_purge_threads    4
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads  4
innodb_read_only    OFF
innodb_replication_delay    0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_rollback_segments    128
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked  OFF
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF
innodb_stats_persistent ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
innodb_status_output    OFF
innodb_status_output_locks  OFF
innodb_strict_mode  ON
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_array_size  1
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_temp_data_file_path  ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
innodb_thread_concurrency   0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000
innodb_tmpdir   
innodb_undo_directory   ./
innodb_undo_log_truncate    OFF
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_native_aio   ON
innodb_version  5.7.37
innodb_write_io_threads 4
interactive_timeout 28800
internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine    InnoDB
join_buffer_size    262144
keep_files_on_create    OFF
key_buffer_size 2147483648
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size    1024
key_cache_division_limit    100
keyring_operations  ON
large_files_support ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages OFF
lc_messages en_US
lc_messages_dir /usr/share/mysql/
lc_time_names   en_US
license GPL
local_infile    ON
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
locked_in_memory    OFF
log_bin OFF
log_bin_basename    
log_bin_index   
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events   OFF
log_builtin_as_identified_by_password   OFF
log_error   stderr
log_error_verbosity 3
log_output  FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF
log_slave_updates   OFF
log_slow_admin_statements   OFF
log_slow_slave_statements   OFF
log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog    ON
log_syslog  OFF
log_syslog_facility daemon
log_syslog_include_pid  ON
log_syslog_tag  
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes  0
log_timestamps  UTC
log_warnings    2
long_query_time 10.000000
low_priority_updates    OFF
lower_case_file_system  OFF
lower_case_table_names  1
master_info_repository  FILE
master_verify_checksum  OFF
max_allowed_packet  1073741824
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size 104857600
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors  100
max_connections 151
max_delayed_threads 20
max_digest_length   1024
max_error_count 64
max_execution_time  0
max_heap_table_size 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
max_join_size   18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data    1024
max_points_in_geometry  65536
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size  0
max_seeks_for_key   18446744073709551615
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    18446744073709551615
metadata_locks_cache_size   1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances   8
min_examined_row_limit  0
multi_range_count   256
myisam_data_pointer_size    6
myisam_max_sort_file_size   9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size    18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options  BACKUP
myisam_repair_threads   1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 8388608
myisam_stats_method nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap OFF
mysql_native_password_proxy_users   OFF
net_buffer_length   16384
net_read_timeout    30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout   60
new OFF
ngram_token_size    2
offline_mode    OFF
old OFF
old_alter_table OFF
old_passwords   0
open_files_limit    1048576
optimizer_prune_level   1
optimizer_search_depth  62
optimizer_switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on,prefer_ordering_index=on
optimizer_trace enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features    greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
optimizer_trace_limit   1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size    16384
optimizer_trace_offset  -1
parser_max_mem_size 18446744073709551615
performance_schema  OFF
performance_schema_accounts_size    0
performance_schema_digests_size 0
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size  0
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size   0
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size  0
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size   0
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size    0
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size 0
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size   0
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    0
performance_schema_hosts_size   0
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 0
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   0
performance_schema_max_digest_length    0
performance_schema_max_file_classes 0
performance_schema_max_file_handles 0
performance_schema_max_file_instances   0
performance_schema_max_index_stat   0
performance_schema_max_memory_classes   0
performance_schema_max_metadata_locks   0
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    0
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  0
performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances    0
performance_schema_max_program_instances    0
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   0
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances 0
performance_schema_max_socket_classes   0
performance_schema_max_socket_instances 0
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length  0
performance_schema_max_stage_classes    0
performance_schema_max_statement_classes    0
performance_schema_max_statement_stack  0
performance_schema_max_table_handles    0
performance_schema_max_table_instances  0
performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat  0
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   0
performance_schema_max_thread_instances 0
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size   0
performance_schema_setup_actors_size    0
performance_schema_setup_objects_size   0
performance_schema_users_size   0
pid_file    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
plugin_dir  /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/
port    3306
preload_buffer_size 32768
profiling   OFF
profiling_history_size  15
protocol_version    10
query_alloc_block_size  8192
query_cache_limit   1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    2097152
query_cache_type    OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
query_prealloc_size 8192
range_alloc_block_size  4096
range_optimizer_max_mem_size    8388608
rbr_exec_mode   STRICT
read_buffer_size    131072
read_only   OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size    65536
relay_log   
relay_log_basename  /var/lib/mysql/41838e92fa49-relay-bin
relay_log_index /var/lib/mysql/41838e92fa49-relay-bin.index
relay_log_info_file relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository   FILE
relay_log_purge ON
relay_log_recovery  OFF
relay_log_space_limit   0
replication_optimize_for_static_plugin_config   OFF
replication_sender_observe_commit_only  OFF
report_host 
report_password 
report_port 3306
report_user 
require_secure_transport    OFF
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000
secure_auth ON
secure_file_priv    /etc/mysql/conf.d/secure-file/
server_id   0
server_id_bits  32
server_uuid 370afbf5-891e-11ec-98df-02fbcfd921e0
session_track_gtids OFF
session_track_schema    ON
session_track_state_change  OFF
session_track_system_variables  time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_results,character_set_connection
session_track_transaction_info  OFF
sha256_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys  ON
sha256_password_private_key_path    private_key.pem
sha256_password_proxy_users OFF
sha256_password_public_key_path public_key.pem
show_compatibility_56   OFF
show_create_table_verbosity OFF
show_old_temporals  OFF
skip_external_locking   ON
skip_name_resolve   OFF
skip_networking OFF
skip_show_database  OFF
slave_allow_batching    OFF
slave_checkpoint_group  512
slave_checkpoint_period 300
slave_compressed_protocol   OFF
slave_exec_mode STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir   /tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824
slave_net_timeout   60
slave_parallel_type DATABASE
slave_parallel_workers  0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max 16777216
slave_preserve_commit_order OFF
slave_rows_search_algorithms    TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
slave_skip_errors   OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum   ON
slave_transaction_retries   10
slave_type_conversions  
slow_launch_time    2
slow_query_log  OFF
slow_query_log_file /var/lib/mysql/41838e92fa49-slow.log
socket  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
sort_buffer_size    262144
sql_auto_is_null    OFF
sql_big_selects ON
sql_buffer_result   OFF
sql_log_off OFF
sql_mode    
sql_notes   ON
sql_quote_show_create   ON
sql_safe_updates    OFF
sql_select_limit    18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter  0
sql_warnings    OFF
ssl_ca  ca.pem
ssl_capath  
ssl_cert    server-cert.pem
ssl_cipher  
ssl_crl 
ssl_crlpath 
ssl_key server-key.pem
stored_program_cache    256
super_read_only OFF
sync_binlog 1
sync_frm    ON
sync_master_info    10000
sync_relay_log  10000
sync_relay_log_info 10000
system_time_zone    UTC
table_definition_cache  1400
table_open_cache    2000
table_open_cache_instances  16
thread_cache_size   64
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack    196608
time_format %H:%i:%s
time_zone   Europe/Paris
tls_version TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
tmp_table_size  16777216
tmpdir  /tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192
transaction_isolation   REPEATABLE-READ
transaction_prealloc_size   4096
transaction_read_only   OFF
transaction_write_set_extraction    OFF
tx_isolation    REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only    OFF
unique_checks   ON
updatable_views_with_limit  YES
version 5.7.37
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
wait_timeout    28800
```

System :
11.5GB RAM
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 - 4x2.5GHZ
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2

I must be more precise in one point.
RAM is growing even if running slow queries, sounds like a mem leak
But I don't know, I prefer to ask to a confirmed DBA

show global status

```
|variable_name |value |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|aborted_clients |218 |
|aborted_connects |1 |
|binlog_cache_disk_use |0 |
|binlog_cache_use |0 |
|binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use |0 |
|binlog_stmt_cache_use |0 |
|bytes_received |563781610 |
|bytes_sent |2691784462 |
|com_admin_commands |713 |
|com_assign_to_keycache |0 |
|com_alter_db |0 |
|com_alter_db_upgrade |0 |
|com_alter_event |0 |
|com_alter_function |0 |
|com_alter_instance |0 |
|com_alter_procedure |0 |
|com_alter_server |0 |
|com_alter_table |0 |
|com_alter_tablespace |0 |
|com_alter_user |0 |
|com_analyze |0 |
|com_begin |0 |
|com_binlog |0 |
|com_call_procedure |11 |
|com_change_db |1770 |
|com_change_master |0 |
|com_change_repl_filter |0 |
|com_check |0 |
|com_checksum |0 |
|com_commit |528 |
|com_create_db |0 |
|com_create_event |0 |
|com_create_function |0 |
|com_create_index |0 |
|com_create_procedure |0 |
|com_create_server |0 |
|com_create_table |0 |
|com_create_trigger |0 |
|com_create_udf |0 |
|com_create_user |0 |
|com_create_view |0 |
|com_dealloc_sql |0 |
|com_delete |165 |
|com_delete_multi |0 |
|com_do |0 |
|com_drop_db |0 |
|com_drop_event |0 |
|com_drop_function |0 |
|com_drop_index |0 |
|com_drop_procedure |0 |
|com_drop_server |0 |
|com_drop_table |0 |
|com_drop_trigger |0 |
|com_drop_user |0 |
|com_drop_view |0 |
|com_empty_query |0 |
|com_execute_sql |0 |
|com_explain_other |0 |
|com_flush |0 |
|com_get_diagnostics |0 |
|com_grant |0 |
|com_ha_close |0 |
|com_ha_open |0 |
|com_ha_read |0 |
|com_help |0 |
|com_insert |5034 |
|com_insert_select |22 |
|com_install_plugin |0 |
|com_kill |0 |
|com_load |0 |
|com_lock_tables |0 |
|com_optimize |0 |
|com_preload_keys |0 |
|com_prepare_sql |0 |
|com_purge |0 |
|com_purge_before_date |0 |
|com_release_savepoint |0 |
|com_rename_table |0 |
|com_rename_user |0 |
|com_repair |0 |
|com_replace |0 |
|com_replace_select |0 |
|com_reset |0 |
|com_resignal |0 |
|com_revoke |0 |
|com_revoke_all |0 |
|com_rollback |18 |
|com_rollback_to_savepoint |0 |
|com_savepoint |0 |
|com_select |2238278 |
|com_set_option |306628 |
|com_signal |0 |
|com_show_binlog_events |0 |
|com_show_binlogs |0 |
|com_show_charsets |1 |
|com_show_collations |225 |
|com_show_create_db |0 |
|com_show_create_event |0 |
|com_show_create_func |0 |
|com_show_create_proc |0 |
|com_show_create_table |0 |
|com_show_create_trigger |0 |
|com_show_databases |3 |
|com_show_engine_logs |0 |
|com_show_engine_mutex |0 |
|com_show_engine_status |0 |
|com_show_events |0 |
|com_show_errors |0 |
|com_show_fields |0 |
|com_show_function_code |0 |
|com_show_function_status |0 |
|com_show_grants |0 |
|com_show_keys |0 |
|com_show_master_status |0 |
|com_show_open_tables |0 |
|com_show_plugins |0 |
|com_show_privileges |0 |
|com_show_procedure_code |0 |
|com_show_procedure_status |0 |
|com_show_processlist |0 |
|com_show_profile |0 |
|com_show_profiles |0 |
|com_show_relaylog_events |0 |
|com_show_slave_hosts |1 |
|com_show_slave_status |1 |
|com_show_status |6 |
|com_show_storage_engines |2 |
|com_show_table_status |7 |
|com_show_tables |1 |
|com_show_triggers |0 |
|com_show_variables |227 |
|com_show_warnings |2535 |
|com_show_create_user |0 |
|com_shutdown |0 |
|com_slave_start |0 |
|com_slave_stop |0 |
|com_group_replication_start |0 |
|com_group_replication_stop |0 |
|com_stmt_execute |2608885 |
|com_stmt_close |2562581 |
|com_stmt_fetch |0 |
|com_stmt_prepare |2609126 |
|com_stmt_reset |0 |
|com_stmt_send_long_data |0 |
|com_truncate |11 |
|com_uninstall_plugin |0 |
|com_unlock_tables |0 |
|com_update |438112 |
|com_update_multi |32 |
|com_xa_commit |0 |
|com_xa_end |0 |
|com_xa_prepare |0 |
|com_xa_recover |0 |
|com_xa_rollback |0 |
|com_xa_start |0 |
|com_stmt_reprepare |0 |
|connection_errors_accept |0 |
|connection_errors_internal |0 |
|connection_errors_max_connections |0 |
|connection_errors_peer_address |0 |
|connection_errors_select |0 |
|connection_errors_tcpwrap |0 |
|connections |3118 |
|created_tmp_disk_tables |38 |
|created_tmp_files |6 |
|created_tmp_tables |100334 |
|delayed_errors |0 |
|delayed_insert_threads |0 |
|delayed_writes |0 |
|flush_commands |1 |
|handler_commit |2599196 |
|handler_delete |62 |
|handler_discover |0 |
|handler_external_lock |5375741 |
|handler_mrr_init |0 |
|handler_prepare |0 |
|handler_read_first |3704 |
|handler_read_key |4366933 |
|handler_read_last |980 |
|handler_read_next |27192648 |
|handler_read_prev |0 |
|handler_read_rnd |3661163 |
|handler_read_rnd_next |200988828 |
|handler_rollback |29 |
|handler_savepoint |0 |
|handler_savepoint_rollback |0 |
|handler_update |462328 |
|handler_write |547400 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status |dumping of buffer pool not started |
|innodb_buffer_pool_load_status |buffer pool(s) load completed at 220209 19:38:04 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status | |
|innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data |52493 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data |860045312 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty |253 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty |4145152 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed |59415 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free |202727 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc |6892 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total |262112 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd |0 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead |11125 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted |0 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests |211353237 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_reads |39970 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free |0 |
|innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests |3268680 |
|innodb_data_fsyncs |449117 |
|innodb_data_pending_fsyncs |0 |
|innodb_data_pending_reads |0 |
|innodb_data_pending_writes |0 |
|innodb_data_read |859460096 |
|innodb_data_reads |52538 |
|innodb_data_writes |501951 |
|innodb_data_written |2607627776 |
|innodb_dblwr_pages_written |59376 |
|innodb_dblwr_writes |5087 |
|innodb_log_waits |0 |
|innodb_log_write_requests |1133618 |
|innodb_log_writes |436974 |
|innodb_os_log_fsyncs |437411 |
|innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs |0 |
|innodb_os_log_pending_writes |0 |
|innodb_os_log_written |661132288 |
|innodb_page_size |16384 |
|innodb_pages_created |165 |
|innodb_pages_read |52328 |
|innodb_pages_written |59415 |
|innodb_row_lock_current_waits |0 |
|innodb_row_lock_time |0 |
|innodb_row_lock_time_avg |0 |
|innodb_row_lock_time_max |0 |
|innodb_row_lock_waits |0 |
|innodb_rows_deleted |0 |
|innodb_rows_inserted |848 |
|innodb_rows_read |182834395 |
|innodb_rows_updated |461299 |
|innodb_num_open_files |36 |
|innodb_truncated_status_writes |0 |
|innodb_available_undo_logs |128 |
|key_blocks_not_flushed |0 |
|key_blocks_unused |1698985 |
|key_blocks_used |1714736 |
|key_read_requests |9086981 |
|key_reads |5980975 |
|key_write_requests |14944 |
|key_writes |14717 |
|locked_connects |0 |
|max_execution_time_exceeded |0 |
|max_execution_time_set |0 |
|max_execution_time_set_failed |0 |
|max_used_connections |71 |
|max_used_connections_time |2022-02-09 21:30:02 |
|not_flushed_delayed_rows |0 |
|ongoing_anonymous_transaction_count |0 |
|open_files |1032 |
|open_streams |0 |
|open_table_definitions |415 |
|open_tables |1414 |
|opened_files |4012 |
|opened_table_definitions |470 |
|opened_tables |2700 |
|performance_schema_accounts_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_cond_classes_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_cond_instances_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_digest_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_file_classes_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_file_handles_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_file_instances_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_hosts_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_index_stat_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_locker_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_memory_classes_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_metadata_lock_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_nested_statement_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_prepared_statements_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_program_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_socket_classes_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_socket_instances_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_stage_classes_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_statement_classes_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_table_handles_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_table_instances_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_table_lock_stat_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_thread_classes_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_thread_instances_lost |0 |
|performance_schema_users_lost |0 |
|prepared_stmt_count |38 |
|qcache_free_blocks |1 |
|qcache_free_memory |2080376 |
|qcache_hits |0 |
|qcache_inserts |0 |
|qcache_lowmem_prunes |0 |
|qcache_not_cached |2237007 |
|qcache_queries_in_cache |0 |
|qcache_total_blocks |1 |
|queries |8173715 |
|questions |2994215 |
|rsa_public_key |-----begin public key-----miibijanbgkqhkig9w0baqefaaocaq8amiibcgkcaqea3qlwke0/0aq0xohgzoodjwwhqwbn|
|select_full_join |675 |
|select_full_range_join |0 |
|select_range |2627 |
|select_range_check |7 |
|select_scan |10688 |
|slave_open_temp_tables |0 |
|slow_launch_threads |0 |
|slow_queries |0 |
|sort_merge_passes |0 |
|sort_range |1233 |
|sort_rows |225233 |
|sort_scan |806 |
|ssl_accept_renegotiates |0 |
|ssl_accepts |88 |
|ssl_callback_cache_hits |0 |
|ssl_cipher | |
|ssl_cipher_list | |
|ssl_client_connects |0 |
|ssl_connect_renegotiates |0 |
|ssl_ctx_verify_depth |18446744073709551615 |
|ssl_ctx_verify_mode |5 |
|ssl_default_timeout |0 |
|ssl_finished_accepts |87 |
|ssl_finished_connects |0 |
|ssl_server_not_after |feb 6 20:32:21 2032 gmt |
|ssl_server_not_before |feb 8 20:32:21 2022 gmt |
|ssl_session_cache_hits |0 |
|ssl_session_cache_misses |0 |
|ssl_session_cache_mode |server |
|ssl_session_cache_overflows |0 |
|ssl_session_cache_size |128 |
|ssl_session_cache_timeouts |0 |
|ssl_sessions_reused |0 |
|ssl_used_session_cache_entries |87 |
|ssl_verify_depth |0 |
|ssl_verify_mode |0 |
|ssl_version | |
|table_locks_immediate |86485 |
|table_locks_waited |28 |
|table_open_cache_hits |5299270 |
|table_open_cache_misses |2678 |
|table_open_cache_overflows |1235 |
|tc_log_max_pages_used |0 |
|tc_log_page_size |0 |
|tc_log_page_waits |0 |
|threads_cached |1 |
|threads_connected |70 |
|threads_created |71 |
|threads_running |1 |
|uptime |3132 |
|uptime_since_flush_status |3132 |
```

Answer (score 0):

@Salim  With available information, suggestions to consider

```
REMOVE from your configuration log_error  to allow default error log file name
innodb_print_all_deadlocks=1  # from OFF to enable identification and pursue correcting.
key_cache_block_size=16384  # from 1024 to reduce overhead managing key_buffer_size
key_cache_division_limit=50  # from 100 percent for Hot and Warm cache
key_cache_age_threshold=7200  # from 300 seconds before AGE-OUT of indx in ram  These three variables, after implementation will reduce key_reads Rate Per Second of 1,910.
```

Observations,
When your log_error is stderr, there is no hope of determining what happened
several hours ago to your server.
com_rollback counted 18 events in 3,131 seconds and you have NO record of the cause with current configuration.  innodb_print_all_deadlocks may help you here.
com_stmt_prepare count is usually paired with com_stmt_close.  In your STATUS, reporting, com_stmt_close indicates 46,545 prepares did not have CLOSE, leaving resources in use.  Reducing ram available over your 3,131 seconds of uptime.